# Skype 5.1 on Windows 7 (Offline all time)

Tags: skype

i am using skype on windows 7, some days it is going offline all the day and can't response even install a new version (5.1) and restart computer several time but still offline can help me out any one how to fix this problem.

Comment: you could try a lower version.. might work out maybe

Answer (score 0):

Just From menu, click on **Skype->Online Status->** then click on **Online** ,it should be solve your problem.